# Login system for only one user

Tags: node.js, authentication

I'm using NodeJS to create a simple blogging platform as a bit of an experiment. However while creating the admin panel (to allow one to compose posts and edit existing ones, change themes, etc.) I realised that I would need to create a login system. I am aware of `passport.js`, however I question the need for a login system where the software will administrated by one user.

My question is, is it necessary to have a login system for a platform that only has one administrator and no other users? If not, what approach should I take for this platform then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it depends on what you want.

1. If you want to make some security relative practices and learn the principles inside, you should do more deeper research about security, and then choose a particular solution.
2. If you just want a 'door', which prevent others from accessing your control panel, and your application is just a simple blog system, not some popular huge system, in this case, I think static password would be good enough to hold, just require a password from user interface(frontend), then send it to your backend(nodejs), check if it's really yourself so that your backend logic can decide whether grant this access(you can hardcode the password in the backend part), done.